# Site fonts on Linux

Tags: bug

After logging on this morning, I noticed that my fonts (using Brave) had all switched back to whatever SE was using before. Is it just me or was the Ubuntu font removed?

Comment: We never had the Ubuntu font here, we might have it _now_ because of [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048) so you might be seeing things in the Ubuntu font if you have it installed. Anyway, I suspect what you are seeing is explained in that meta SE link.

Comment: OK, that explains it.